# Настройка Owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Задача стоит в том, чтобы сделать центральное изображение самым большим, по сторонам от него средние и совсем крайние маленькие - fish eye, так сказать.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

            var cssSmall = {
                width: 100,
                marginTop: 75
            };
            var cssMedium = {
                width: 250,
                marginTop: 35
            };
            var cssLarge = {
                width: 400,
                marginTop: 0
            };


    $('.owl-carousel').on('translate.owl.carousel', function(e){
    idx = e.item.index;
    $('.owl-item').eq(idx-2).css(cssSmall);
    $('.owl-item').eq(idx+2).css(cssSmall);
    $('.owl-item').eq(idx-1).css(cssMedium);
    $('.owl-item').eq(idx+1).css(cssMedium);
    $('.owl-item').eq(idx).css(cssLarge);
});

            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                nav:true,
                navText: ["предыдущая", "следующая"],
                items: 5,
                loop: true,
                startPosition: 3,
                margin: 10,
                center:true,
                dots: false,
            });

        })
```

Я пытался сделать так, но при loop:true получается какая-то ерунда, изображения друг на друга накладываюстя. Хотелось бы, чтобы было вот так http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/17/

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы забыли подключить CSS основной и theme без них бардак будет. Удачи.